# Selecting the same row between 2 tables relative to the ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner with SQL syntax.  I have 2 tables called `STUDENT` and `EXAMINATION` and I am, in 1 line, trying to write a query to print `ID`, `SUBJECT` and `NUMBER_OF_TIMES`.  I am not told which column belongs to which table but my guess is that `ID` belongs to `STUDENT` and `SUBJECT` belongs to `EXAMINATION`.  `NUMBER_OF_TIMES` is just how many times the same student has taken that subject exam.

I tried `SELECT STUDENT.ID, EXAMINATION.SUBJECT, NUMBER_OF_TIMES` but no luck.

Comment: You absolutely should find some way to get the table structure here.  Having to guess to which table a given belongs is an overall bad way to write SQL code.

Comment: I've just confirmed it.  My guess was right.

Comment: at first, if you share the structure of your tables, we can help you better, but at all, You should join two tables on the field which has a relationship between two tables and use count function on 'ID' column group by student 'ID'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your working query would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    s.ID,
    e.SUBJECT,
    COUNT(e.STUDENT_ID) AS cnt
FROM STUDENT s
LEFT JOIN EXAMINATION e
    ON s.ID = e.STUDENT_ID
GROUP BY
    s.ID,
    e.SUBJECT
```

This answer assumes, really out of necessity, that there exists a join column `STUDENT_ID` in the exam table, which connects with the student table.  We use a left join so as to report all students, even those with a zero count.

Comment: What if I have the same tables STUDENT & EXAMINATION where I need to only output the ID, STUDENT.NAME and EXAMINATION.SUBJECT and replace the EXAMINATION.SUBJECT with null if a student doesn't have one?  Outlut like this: 2 Jerry NULL, 5 Mike English, and so on.

Comment: I suggest that you ask a new question, and include the following items: full table structure for all tables invovled, sample input table data, and the expected output.